# UWP media element codec

Tags: win-universal-app, codec, flv, mediaelement

I want to known how UWP mediaelement can play all type of files, like flv and mkv as well. I searched it already and found ffmpeg for it, but the problem I am facing is that ffmpegintrop project of c++ is giving an error to refrence in my UWP project of c#, any guidance regarding the matter would be great, or if anyone could tell me any other way to achieve the same purpose. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is FFmpegInterop Samples for win10 https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/tree/master/Samples

And here is instruction how to build it https://github.com/Microsoft/FFmpegInterop/blob/master/README.md

It should work (works for me on 8.1 winrt).

Comment: i read the instructions, ive cloned the projects but then there is detail link for compilation/build, and that link is not working :(

Comment: @MuhammadTouseef Compile and Use FFmpeg Libraries for Windows Runtime (Windows 10 or Windows 8.1 Apps)
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/WinRT

Comment: yes i tried this link due to some reason this link is not working

Comment: I am having trouble building it i completed almost all the steps properly but at the end when i run the 'make' command it doesnt work, what should i write at the place of '--prefix-- in the second last command? @RavingDev